# Recevie a blank white screen after logging into Salesforce1 (only occurs on Samsung 4s devices)

Tags: salesforce1-app

Running into an issue with Samsung 4s devices. Once a user logins into the Salesforce1 app they only get a blank white screen. Other Android and IOS devices work fine

Comment: Sounds like the same issue as [this one](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68450/blank-screen-logging-a-call-in-salesforce-1)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but with an iOS user. Salesforce support suggested that it could be a cache issue on the app, and the solution is to uninstall and reinstall the app. Updating the app does not clear cache, so it must be uninstalled.

Still waiting to hear from the user on if this solved her problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, I fixed this by going into app manager and clearing the cache myself.